# Crosstab query with TRANSFORM and PIVOT is repeating rows

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, pivot, transform

The query below will be used to retrieve results in my database which will then be inserted into a jtable.

```
TRANSFORM ABS(a.present)
SELECT e.ID, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.position, e.rate 
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN attendance a ON e.ID = a.empID
GROUP BY e.ID, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.position, e.rate, a.present 
PIVOT a.dateAttended
```

The results that were retrieved by the query can be seen below.

[image]

Now, what I would like to do is to merged some results. The problem in my query arises when the result from the date columns differ, (e.g. 1 | 0, or 0 | 1). The ID result is being duplicated (encircled in red). I just want to ask some possible ways on how i can merged the results as seen in the right part of the image. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to TRANSFORM (i.e., report the value of) `a.present` but you have also included that field the GROUP BY clause. Try using `TRANSFORM First(Abs(a.present))` and removing `a.present` from the GROUP BY clause, i.e.,

```sql
TRANSFORM First(Abs(a.present))
SELECT e.ID, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.position, e.rate 
FROM employees e LEFT JOIN attendance a ON e.ID = a.empID
GROUP BY e.ID, e.firstName, e.lastName, e.position, e.rate
PIVOT a.dateAttended
```